# NSS-LDAP not working over TLS: do_open: do_start_tls failed:stat=-1

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap, starttls, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using NSS-LDAP for authentication. Without TLS, everything works fine. Once I enable TLS (StartTLS) with a self-signed certificate, which I have added to the client, NSS-LDAP won't connect to the LDAP server.

```
systemctl status nscd
```

gives

```
nss-ldap: do_open: do_start_tls failed:stat=-1
nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
```

I can connect to the server with `ldapsearch -Z ...` without any problems.

My `/etc/ldap.conf` looks like this:

```
...
uri ldap:///192.168.8.8
...
ssl start_tls 
tls_cacertdir /etc/ssl/certs
```

Comment: You have a self-signed cert for an IP address? It's doable, but rare. Does -ZZ work? Also note that ldapsearch usually uses in the configuration in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`, while the ns and pam ldap libraries tend to use `/etc/ldap.conf`.

Comment: @84104 Yes, ZZ did work. Though not I've scrapped nss-ldap in favor of sssd, which has resolved the issue